# Facade design pattern over data types

Tags: oop, design-patterns, facade

I have a class named `MyClass` in subsystem A, and a method in subsystem B has arguments of type `MyClass`. My subsystems are highly coupled, so I want to make a Facade for subsystem A. Should I somehow pass the `MyClass` type trough the Facade? What is the right way?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends (tm), but it's usually a good idea to have separate classes that are used by an API and classes that are internal to the system. If for whatever reason `MyClass` needs to change in System A, you probably don't want that change to cascade and impact System B.

In your example, if each subsystem should be as loosely coupled as possible, one approach would be to have an [adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) that is external to both subsystems, but it's able to adapt the calls from one to the other.

Just a word of caution, overusing design patterns is not a good idea. I think in your example it's worth asking oneself if the subsystems should be separate or if they are one.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if subsystem A and B are close enough, it's natural for MyClass to be coupled like this?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Having very loosely coupled systems is good, but if one makes those systems too small, then the maintenance and complexity goes up. The same happens with a big system that has a lot of accidental coupling. There's a fine balance between both, and that's why refactoring is so important in order to bring that balance back.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the scenario correctly, you have this direction of coupling:

```
B -> MyClass
```

where the arrow indicates the direction of dependence.

If you make a Facade for subsystem A, the dependencies will now look like this:

```
B -> Facade -> MyClass
```

Thus, *B* will still depend transitively on *MyClass*.

If you want to decouple subsystem B from subsystem A, consider the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle):

> - High-level modules should not import anything from low-level modules. Both should depend on abstractions (e.g., interfaces).
> - Abstractions should not depend on details. Details (concrete implementations) should depend on abstractions.

Thus, let subsystem B define the abstraction that *it* needs, and then let the detail implement the abstraction. It may look like this:

```
B -> Interface <- MyClass
```

If you put the interface in subsystem B, you've now reversed the direction of dependence, but you can also put the interface in a separate subsystem so that both A and B depend on the abstraction, but not on each other.